# Occasional javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException

Tags: jsf, ejb, ejb-3.0

My website gives this `javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException`  exception ***occasionaly***.
It shows pages with no problem but sometimes it gives the following exception and i don't know what is the problem.

Searching about the problem, i already increased the `max-thread-pool-size` to 10.

```
Exception Processing ErrorPage[exceptionType=javax.ejb.EJBException, location=/errorpages/404.xhtml]
javax.servlet.ServletException
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:577)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.mapLocal3xException(BaseContainer.java:2279)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2060)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy325.getUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
    at com.suggestboard.ejbs.__EJB31_Generated__UserFacade__Intf____Bean__.getUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1258.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:396)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:108)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:101)
    at com.suggestboard.ejbs.UserFacade$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.getUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
    at com.suggestboard.beans.UserManager.getCurrentUser(UserManager.java:43)
    at com.suggestboard.beans.UserManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getCurrentUser(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1248.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstEmpty.getValue(AstEmpty.java:66)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:63)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:457)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1850)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Client's transaction aborted
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.useClientTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:357)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.preInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:251)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4433)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1921)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
    ... 72 more
```

Comment: The problem is that it gives this exception occasionally not always. I get an empty page if this exception occurs. When i refresh the page it works fine. I suspect JPA part. Normally it shouldn't even redirect to error page because i request a valid page. By the way rendered="#{not empty userManager.currentUser}" is necessary in the 404.xhtml. Actually rendered="#{not empty userManager.currentUser}" is inside a template which is used by error.xhtml

Comment: @BalusC Try this link, refresh a few times and you will get empty pages sometimes. 
http://www.suggestboard.com/users.xhtml?id=12

Comment: Do you inadvertently swallow/consume some exceptions before this exception is triggered (not only swallowed exceptions but there might be some other errors too that may occur before this exception is thrown)? Those consumed exceptions may have been thrown (before) and your code still attempts to perform some database tasks hereby the transaction is marked for rollback (or aborted)?

Comment: @Tiny but then shouldn't i get exception every time i refresh the page. I only get this exception sometimes.